# Trying to understand “PT1H” in a date-time string

Tags: timezone, timezone-offset

I'm using the Weather API to pull weather information down as a service for my project.  I'm trying to understand some timezone offsets that I can't seem to find information on.

The URL I'm using is:

```
https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/VEF/154,48
```

Here is some sample return values:

```
"temperature": {
    "sourceUnit": "F",
    "uom": "unit:degC",
    "values": [
        {
            "validTime": "2019-05-11T16:00:00+00:00/PT1H",
            "value": 18.333333333333371
        },
        {
            "validTime": "2019-05-12T04:00:00+00:00/PT2H",
            "value": 16.1111111111112
        },
        {
            "validTime": "2019-05-12T21:00:00+00:00/PT4H",
            "value": 26.666666666666742
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I understand the **PT** means Pacific Timezone.  But I cant seem to find any information on the next to characters like **1H**, **2H**, etc.

If anyone can advise that would be appreciated - Thanks

Comment: Explained here: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: There's no "Pacific Timezone" - the Pacific Ocean touches many zones.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## `PT1H` = One hour

> I understand the PT means Pacific Timezone.

No, incorrect assumption. Not a time zone.

The `PT1H` represents a [duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), a span of time not tied to the timeline. This format is defined in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

- The `P` marks the beginning, short for “Period” I imagine, a synonym for duration.
- The `T` separates any years-months-days portion from any hours-minutes-seconds portion. Short for “Time” I suppose.

So `PT1H` means “one hour”. Two and a half hours would be `PT2H30M`.

## Parsing

Your input `"2019-05-11T16:00:00+00:00/PT1H"` combining a starting moment with a duration is [part of the ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) standard.

Such a combo string can be parsed by the [`Interval.parse`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) method found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library.

```
Interval interval = Interval.parse( "2019-05-11T16:00:00+00:00/PT1H" ) ;
```

An `Interval` represents a pair of moments, a pair of [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) objects. In your case here, the second moment is calculated, by adding the duration to the starting moment. We can interrogate for the pair of moments, represented as [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) objects (always in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) by definition).

```
Instant start = interval.getStart() ;
Instant stop = interval.getEnd() ;
```

Comment: You are right the following website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 gives a good description.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that "period" and "duration" are synonyms in *some* contexts but not others - e.g. in `java.time`, where they have quite distinct (but related) meanings. It's unfortunate, but worth a warning IMO.